# Did Gauss know Jacobi's four squares theorem?

Tags: number-theory, theta-functions

This is a question that I have already asked on HSM stackexchange, and I decided to ask it again here because it is more mathematical than historic (to make a conclusion in this question one needs more mathematical then historical understanding). In p. 283-285 of volume 2 of Dickson's “history of the theory of numbers” appear several formulas of striking similarity: some of them are stated by Gauss (p.283) and some are stated by Jacobi (p.285); they are actually the same and only the notation differs ($x$ in Gauss's formula and $q$ in Jacobi's formula). Gauss's formulas are the following identities on the 4th power of the theta function:

$(\sum_{-\infty}^\infty q^{{n^2}})^4 = (\sum_{-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n q^{{n^2}})^4 + (\sum_{-\infty}^\infty q^{{(2n - 1)^2/4}})^4 = 1 + 8\sum_{1\le m} \frac {{mq^m}}{{1 - (-1)^{m + 1}q^m}} = 1 + \sum_{1 \le m}\hat \sigma (k)q^k$

The point is that the last equality means that the coefficients of the $k$th power in the right side of the last equallity must be equal to $r_4(k)$ (number of representations of $k$ as sum of $4$ squares), and an additonal interpretation (by certain manipulations) of the right side of the equallity gives the result of Jacobi: $r_4(k) = 8\sigma(k)$ or $24\sigma(k)$, depends if k is odd or even.

In the [same passage from Gauss's nachlass](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235999628?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B452%5D,%22panX%22:0.485,%22panY%22:0.702,%22view%22:%22toc%22,%22zoom%22:0.437%7D) (Werke, volume 3, p. 444-445, passage [9])  in which he writes down Jacobi's identity, and just before this identity, Gauss also writes down $\mathbb{log}(\vartheta_3^4(x))$ as:

$$\mathbb{log}((1+2x+2x^4+2x^9+\cdots)^4) = 8\cdot (\frac{x}{1+x}+\frac{x^3}{3(1+x^3)}+\frac{x^5}{5(1+x^5)}+\cdots)$$,

(actually he writes down the series for $\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{log}(\vartheta_3(x))$, but it is equivalent to what I wrote). Immediately after writing down several identities on the fourth powers of Jacobi theta functions $p,q,r$, Gauss proceeds and writes a differential equation satisfied by new variables $t,u$ (defined by : $t = \frac{1}{p^2}, u  = \frac{1}{q^2}$)  and their first, second and third derivatives (of $t,u$).

Since I'm unfamiliar with the theory of modular forms, I'm unable to see how Gauss arrived at this identity for $\mathbb{log}(\vartheta_3^4(x))$, nor I'm able to see how one can find the series developement of $\vartheta_3^4(x)$ from that of $\mathbb{log}(\vartheta_3^4(x))$. But maybe some of the mathematicians here who are familiar with modular forms can see the connection.

**Update (July 23, 2022)**

The identity for $\mathbb{log}(\vartheta_3(x))$ can be derived on the basis of Jacobi triple product indentity; it is essensially an expansion of the logarithm into a linear combination of Lambert series by transforming the logarithm of the infinite product form of the theta function (which is a special case of Jacobi triple product) into an infinite sum of logarithms. A detailed derivation of it can be found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497268/how-to-prove-an-identity-of-gauss-for-the-logarithm-of-jacobi-theta-function).

But I believe the key to uncover the infinite series for $\vartheta^4_3(x)$ from that of $\mathbb{log}(\vartheta^4_3(x))$ is the differential equation Gauss writes at the end of passage 9 - he defines $t = \frac{1}{p^2}, u = \frac{1}{q^2}$ where $p = \vartheta_3(x), q = \vartheta_4(x)$ and then writes down several relations, and one of them is:
$$\frac{u}{t}-\frac{t}{u}=2x(tu'-ut')$$
Rewriting it in terms of $p,q,r$, one gets:
$$\frac{p^2}{q^2}-\frac{q^2}{p^2}=2x(tu'-ut')\implies \frac{p^4-q^4}{p^2q^2}=2x(tu'-ut')\implies p^4-q^4 = 2p^2q^2x(tu'-ut') \implies r^4 = \frac{2x}{tu}(tu'-ut')\implies r^4 = 2x(\frac{u'}{u}-\frac{t'}{t})\implies r^4 = 2x(\mathbb{log}'(u) - \mathbb{log}'(t))\implies r^4 = x\mathbb{log'}(\frac{u^2}{t^2}) = x\mathbb{log}'(\frac{p^4}{q^4})$$

I dont know how to prove this differential equation, but this development shows that it connects the logarithm of ratio of theta functions with the fourth power of another theta function ($r$), so this might be the original method Gauss used to arrive at the series for $\vartheta^4_3(x)$. In addition, since $q(x) = p(-x)$, the right side of the last equation, which is $$x(\mathbb{log}'(p(x)^4)-\mathbb{log}'(q(x)^4)) = x(\mathbb{log}'(p(x)^4)-\mathbb{log}'(p(-x)^4))$$, can be calculated on the basis of the series expansion for $\mathbb{log}(p(x))$. This produces Jacobi's identity for the generating function of $r^4(x)$. However, I still dont know how to derive the series for $p^4,q^4$, nor I am able to prove the differential equation stated by Gauss.

Comment: My question is very historical in nature but requires deep mathematical understanding in order to answer it (i'm doing a historical project on C.F Gauss). In other words, my question can be reformulated as: does the derivation of the identities of Gauss imply that Gauss possesed the critical techniques for proving the four squares theorem? and in addition was Gauss aware of the interpretation of his results on theta functions as  being related to the sum of squares function?

Comment: Thus to answer we need to write down the sketch proof and techniques. Do you have some of them ? And it is clear Gauss knew $(\sum_n q^{n^2})^2 =1+4 \sum_k  q^k \sum_{d | k} \chi_4(d)$ (Fermat two square theorem)

Comment: I know how to deduce from Gauss's identity: $(\sum_{-\infty}^\infty q^{{n^2}})^4 =  1 + 8\sum_{1\le m} \frac {{mq^m}}{{1 - (-1)^{m + 1}q^m}}$ the specific form of Jacobi's theorem - $r_4(k) = 8\sigma(k)$ or $24\sigma(k)$, depends if k is odd or even (by using elementary number theoretic demonstrations) . But i have no idea how to derive this identity; according to what i've read, it's derived from the advanced mathematical theories of elliptic functions, theta functions and modular forms.

Comment: To make the deduction, one simply needs to notice that the sum is actually a double sum $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n (\sum _{k = 1}^\infty (-1)^{(k+1)(n+1)}q^{kn})$ , a result of expansion in a geometric series.

Comment: For the method using that both sides are modular forms $\in M_2(\Gamma_0(4))$, see p.33 [here](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Fred%20Diamond%20Jerry%20Shurman%20A%20First%20Course%20in%20Modular%20Forms.pdf)

Comment: Ok i saw the book and it's very advanced for me. Just a question - how page 33 is connected to my question?

Answer (score 4):

Gauss knew a whole lot about theta functions and their modular properties. But his ideas regarding these functions were published posthumously. You can find a detailed description of the development done by Gauss in the famous paper of David Cox titled [*AGM of Gauss*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/248675540_The_Arithmetic-Geometric_Mean_of_Gauss).