# Interpretation of a certain general theorem used by Gauss in his work on theta functions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, math-history, theta-functions

I'm trying to understand the meaning of a general proposition stated by Gauss in a posthomous paper (this paper is in pp. 470-481 of volume 3 of Gauss's werke) on theta functions, a proposition which seems to serve as a guiding and organizing principle of the vast amount of relations among theta functions that he found.

**Gauss's notation and definitions**

Denote by $P(x,y),Q(x,y),R(x,y)$ the following functions:

$$P(x,y)=1+x(y+\frac{1}{y})+x^4(y^2+\frac{1}{y^2})+x^9(y^3+\frac{1}{y^3})+...$$
$$Q(x,y)= 1-x(y+\frac{1}{y})+x^4(y^2+\frac{1}{y^2})-x^9(y^3+\frac{1}{y^3})+...$$
$$R(x,y)=x^{\frac{1}{4}}(y^{\frac{1}{2}}+y^{-\frac{1}{2}})+x^{\frac{9}{4}}(y^{\frac{3}{2}}+y^{-\frac{3}{2}})+x^{\frac{25}{4}}(y^{\frac{5}{2}}+y^{-\frac{5}{2}})+...$$

These functions include Jacobi theta functions in their usual meaning as special cases; if $y$ is a complex number whose absolute value is $1$, and $z$ is defined to be a real number such that $y = e^{2iz}$, then we have:

$$P(x,y)=1+2cos(2z)x+2cos(4z)x^4+2cos(6z)x^9+...=\vartheta_3(z,x)$$

which follows from the identity $cos(2nz)= \frac{e^{2inz}+e^{-2inz}}{2}$. In paticular, we have:

$$P(x,1)=1+2x+2x^4+2x^9+...=\vartheta_3(0,x)$$,
So one can understand $P(x,y),Q(x,y),R(x,y)$ as a generalization of Jacobi theta function $\vartheta(z,x)$ from purely real $z$ to a complex $z$ (non-zero imaginary part of z), so that $|y| \ne 1$.

***Remark:*** I'm not very familiar with Jacobi's publications, so it's quite possible that Jacobi's original definition of his theta functions includes also the case when $z$ is complex, so Gauss's functions $P(x,y),Q(x,y),R(x,y)$ are nothing else than simply Jacobi's theta functions with different notation.

**Gauss's theorem**

On August 6, 1827, Gauss stated the following "general theorem":

$$P(x,ty)\cdot P(x,\frac{y}{t}) = P(x^2,t^2)P(x^2,y^2) + R(x^2,t^2)R(x^2,y^2) $$

and then goes on to derive a multitude of relations from it.

For more comprehensive background on this question, please look at the answer to HSM stackexchange post https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6256/did-gauss-know-jacobis-four-squares-theorem.

Therefore, i'd like to know how to interpret the general theorem stated by Gauss.

Comment: The paper linked in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2610651/72031) gives a good account of theory of theta functions developed by Gauss.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh - i'm aware of this paper, but this article focuses primarily on Gauss's work on the agm, which, from the point of view of modular equations, corresponds to a second order modular tansformation (Landen's transformation). Also, the relevant page in Gauss's Nachlass (volume 3, p. 470), isn't referenced in Cox's article. That's why i think the part of Gauss's work that deals with modular equations and his "general theorem" on theta functions  (the same general theorem mentioned in the title of my question) needs seperate discussion.

Comment: I think my answer is a good interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the Gauss theta functions can be written as

$$ P(x,y) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} x^{n^2}y^n,\;\;
   R(x,y) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}+\frac12} x^{n^2}y^n. \tag{1} $$

Now consider the product of two theta functions

$$ S := P(x,ty)\cdot P(x,y/t) = \left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} x^{n^2}(ty)^n\right) \!
   \left(\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}} x^{m^2}(y/t)^m\right). \tag{2} $$

This can be rewritten as a double sum

$$ S = \sum_{n,m\in\mathbb{Z}} x^{n^2+m^2} y^{n+m}t^{n-m}. \tag{3} $$

Rewrite this using new variables

$$ j = \frac{n+m}2,\;\; k = \frac{n-m}2 \;\; \text{ where }
  \;\; n = j+k,\;\; m = j-k \tag{4} $$

to get

$$ S = \sum_{n,m\in\mathbb{Z}} x^{2(j^2+k^2)} y^{2j}t^{2k}. \tag{5} $$

The double sum $\,S\,$ splits into two cases. One is
$\,S_0\,$ where $\,n,m\,$ have the same parity with
$\,j,k\in\mathbb{Z}.\,$
The other is
$\,S_1\,$ where $\,n,m\,$ have different parity with
$\,j,k\in\mathbb{Z}+\frac12.\,$
Rewrite the sums as products

$$ S_0 = \sum_{j,k\in\mathbb{Z}} (x^2)^{k^2}(t^2)^k \cdot
(x^2)^{j^2}(y^2)^j = P(x^2,t^2)P(x^2,y^2) \tag{6} $$

and

$$ S_1 = \sum_{j,k\in\mathbb{Z}+\frac12} (x^2)^{k^2}(t^2)^k \cdot
(x^2)^{j^2}(y^2)^j = R(x^2,t^2)R(x^2,y^2). \tag{7} $$

The end result is

$$ S = S_0+S_1 = P(x^2,t^2)P(x^2,y^2) + R(x^2,t^2)R(x^2,y^2). \tag{8} $$

I think that this is similar to what Gauss' original proof was but
I have no way to know that. This approach must be very old.

Comment: thanks! i followed your proof and completely understood it (the proof is elementary and doesn't use deep mathematical ideas).  Just one correction - in equation (3)- shouldnt it be $t^{n-m}$ and $y^{n+m}$?

Comment: @user2554 Yes, of course! Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Nice elementary proof +1. I wish modern textbooks also follow similar approaches for theta and elliptic functions. I don't really get their obsession with proofs based on modular forms and complex analysis in general.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the variables $q, z$ with $q=x, y=e^{2iz}$ so that $$P(x, y) =\vartheta_3(z,q),Q(x,y)=\vartheta_4(z,q),R(x,y)=\vartheta_2(z,q)$$ and we can now transcribe the general theorem of Gauss as $$\vartheta_3(z+w,q)\vartheta_3(z-w,q)=\vartheta_3(2z,q^2)\vartheta_3(2w,q^2)+\vartheta_2(2z,q^2)\vartheta_2(2w,q^2)$$ (with $t=e^{2iw}$) as an identity between Jacobi theta functions.

This is one of the most fundamental identities between theta functions and almost all algebraic relations between theta functions can be derived using this. You may have a look at [this paper at arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.04603) for some identities derived via this general theorem of Gauss

The proof of the same can be given by considering the ratio of left and right sides and showing that it is a doubly periodic functions with no poles. And thus is a constant. It requires some effort to show that the constant is $1$ but can be shown with some algebraic manipulation on the series corresponding to these functions with $z=0,w=0$.

---

At the moment I don't have a direct algebraic proof of the above identity and will need to check Jacobi *Fundamenta Nova* to see if Jacobi provided any such proof. Also as you have remarked in your question, Jacobi Theta functions are defined for all complex $z, q$ with $|q|<1$.

Comment: Thanks! The form in which you put the general theorem of Gauss is much more transparent and clear! Obviously i voted your answer because it's helpful, but i still cannot accept it because it lacks explanation why the identity is so central and general (Gauss used it to derive 3,5, and 7th order modular eqations).

Comment: @user2554: the identity in your question concerns a relation between functions of $x$ and $x^2$ and hence can be used to derive modular equations of degree $2$. For degree 3 or 5 or 7 you will need relations between functions of $x, x^3$ or $x, x^5$ or $x, x^7$. I don't think we can get these modular equations from this identity.

Comment: @user2554: I have added a reference paper which illustrates the power of this general theorem of Gauss to derive many identities.

Comment: thanks for the reference. Although it's not directly connected with this question (initialy i thought it's connected), can you also comment about two identities of Gauss on theta functions which appear on article 10 of the posthomous fragment mentioned in my question? I also wrote those identities in the answer to the HSM question which i linked to. Those identities are very interesting since they allowed a later mathematician to count the number of times a given quaternary quadratic form represents an arbitrary integer $n$.

Comment: I just want to save myself the effort of writing another question...

Comment: @user2554: those two identities are mixed modular equations of degree 3 and 9. Essentially they connect functions of $x, x^3,x^{1/3}$ (or equivalently $x, x^3,x^9$) and you can see that the term $9x^2$ in quadratic form comes from the functions related to $x^9$ in the identity. Ramanujan also gave this modular equation using his own version of theta functions.

Comment: your comments help a lot. One last question - can you add a link to a paper that discusses this result of Ramanujan (the mixed modular equation that connects theta functions of $x,x^3,x^9$)?

Comment: @user2554: A nice reference is *Pi and the AGM* by Borwein. See *Cubic Modular Identities* on page 142 which deals with Ramanujan Identities.

Comment: i appologize for interrupting you once again, but after looking into p. 142 of the book you refered to, i didn't became convinced that Ramanujan's theorem is equivalent to Gauss's identities. I tried to symplify Gauss's identites, but these identities contain a term which is a triple product of three theta functions functions - $(pqr)^{\frac{4}{3}}$ - and i have no idea how to reduce such terms to a form similar to Ramanujan's theorem. So can you explain, or at least outline in general, a way of proving equivalency between Gauss's identities and Ramanujan's theorem?

Comment: @user2554: OK i will have a look at the Identity of Gauss and try to derive it via Ramanujan's. In the meanwhile you can try to post a separate question for this as I don't want to put a lot of discussion in comments.

Comment: @user2554: btw, we have $$pqr=2x^{1/4}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-x^{2n})^{3}$$ so that some simplification is possible. This is a standard identity based on product form of theta functions.

Comment: @user2554: also note that your two identities are just one because we can get the second one from first by replacing $x$ with $-x$.