# Finding a concise relation between $\operatorname{ns}\left(\frac{K(k)}{3},k\right)$ and $\operatorname{ns}\left(\frac{2K(k)}{3},k\right)$

Tags: correlation, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

Let $\operatorname{ns}\left(z,k\right)$ be one of the Jacobi's elliptic functions, and $K(k)$ the complete elliptic integral of the first kind. It's well-known that $\operatorname{ns}(mK(k),k)$ where $m\in\mathbb{Q}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is always an algebraic function with respect to $k$. With its [addition formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/JacobiNS/16/02/),
$$
\operatorname{ns}\left ( u+v ,k\right )\operatorname{ns}
\left ( u-v,k \right ) 
=\frac{k^2-\operatorname{ns}(u,k)^2\operatorname{ns}(v,k)^2}{
\operatorname{ns}(u,k)^2-\operatorname{ns}(v,k)^2},
$$
place $(u,v)=\left ( \frac{2}{3}K(k), \frac{1}{3}K(k)  \right )$ and $(u,v)=\left ( K(k), \frac13K(k)  \right )$ respectively, giving
\begin{aligned}
&\operatorname{ns}\left ( \frac{2}{3}K(k),k  \right )^2
=\frac{k^2-\operatorname{ns}\left ( \frac{1}{3}K(k),k  \right )^2 }{
1-\operatorname{ns}\left ( \frac{1}{3}K(k),k  \right )^2} \\
&\operatorname{ns}\left ( \frac{1}{3}K(k),k  \right )
=\frac{k^2-\operatorname{ns}\left ( \frac{2}{3}K(k),k  \right )^2\operatorname{ns}\left ( \frac{1}{3}K(k),k  \right )^2}{
\operatorname{ns}\left ( \frac{2}{3}K(k),k  \right )^2-\operatorname{ns}\left ( \frac{1}{3}K(k),k  \right )^2} 
\end{aligned}
The two equations are linear independent with each other, producing exact expressions of $\operatorname{ns}\left ( \frac{1}{3}K(k),k  \right ),\operatorname{ns}\left ( \frac{2}{3}K(k),k  \right )$. But the nasty appearances make it hard to do for some calculation. So is there a concise algebraic relation between the two? Thanks for your help.

---

My ultimate goal is to develop another way to calculate some algebraic number $k_n$ which satisfying $K^\prime(k)/K(k)=\sqrt{n}$. And $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,16,18...$ can be evaluated, whereas $k_{7},k_{15}...$ can't because the restriction of `Wolfram Cloud`(I use it to solve equations). Basic ideas are recorded [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4651814/). It signifies the need of relations among $\operatorname{ns}\left (mK(k),k  \right )$ having the same denominator.

Comment: I'm working on the same problem. Being: 
\begin{align*}
P(q)=1-24\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nq^{n}}{1-q^{n}}.
\end{align*}
It can be shown that: $$1+k^2=\frac{6P(q^2)-3P(q)}{4P(q^4)-P(q)},$$
when $q=e^{-\pi\frac{K(k')}{K(k)}}$. The a recurrence relation is derived.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions) gives the relation $\text{cn} (2K/3,k)=1-\text{sn}(K/3,k)$ which translates to $\text{ns}(2K/3,k)=\dfrac{\text{ns}(K/3,k)}{\sqrt{2\, \text{ns}(K/3,k)-1}}$

Comment: @User: just curious, how does your formula relate to evaluation of singular moduli $k_n$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh sure, I will give full details as soon as possible.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh it can be shown only knowing the first singular moduli ($k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$) that: $$P(e^{-\pi/2})=\frac{12}{\pi}-\frac{\Gamma({1/4})^4\left(\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{4}+\frac{9}{8} \right)}{\pi^3},$$
$$P(e^{-\pi})=\frac{6}{\pi}-\frac{12\Gamma({1/4})^4}{32\pi^3},$$
$$P(e^{-2\pi})=\frac{3}{\pi},$$
$$P(e^{-4\pi})=\frac{3\Gamma({1/4})^4}{32\pi^3}+\frac{3}{2\pi},$$
$$P(e^{-8\pi})=\frac{\Gamma({1/4})^4\left(3\sqrt{2}/64+9/128\right)}{\pi^3}+\frac{3}{4\pi},$$
$$P(e^{-16\pi})=\frac{\Gamma({1/4})^4\left(3(2^{1/4}+2^{3/4})/128+9\sqrt{2}/256+21/512\right)}{\pi^3}+\frac{3}{8\pi}.$$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh inserting these values on: $$1+k^2=\frac{6P(q^2)-3P(q)}{4P(q^4)-P(q)},$$
when $q=e^{-\pi\frac{K(k')}{K(k)}}$. Gives some singular moduli. As I said the process can be iterated.

Comment: @User: If your objective is to find the values of $k_{2^n}$ starting from $k_1=2^{-1/2}$ then one can directly use the Landen transformation without much hassle. I won't comment further here as this may seem like a digression with respect to current question.

Answer (score 3):

Define the two quantities

$$ a_1 := \text{ns}\left(\frac{K(k)}{3},k\right) \quad\text{ and }
\quad a_2 := \text{ns}\left(\frac{2K(k)}{3},k\right). \tag1 $$

The power series for these using the notation $\,k^2 = 16x\,$ is

$$ a_1 = 2 - 6 x - 30 x^2 - 258 x^3 - 2694 x^4 - 31128 x^5 - \dots,\\
a_2 = (2 - 2 x - 10 x^2 - 82 x^3 - 818 x^4 - 9076 x^5 -\dots)/\sqrt{3}.
\tag2 $$

The question asked is

> So is there a concise algebraic relation between the two?

The answer is
$$ a_2 = \frac{a_1}{\sqrt{2a_1-1}} \quad \text{ and }
\quad a_1 = a_2^2 + \sqrt{a_2^4-a_2^2}. \tag3 $$

Other algebraic relations are
$$ 0 = a_1^4 - 2a_1^3 + 2k^2a_1 - k^2, \\
0 = 3a_2^8 - 4(1+k^2)a_2^6 + 6k^2a_2^4 - k^4. \tag4 $$